# В ToolBox недоступны элементы Visual-Studio

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli

В Toolbox просто недоступны элементы.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перезапуск VS не помог.

Comment: Здравствуйте как вы решили проблему? То у меня такая же

Comment: Как именно был создан проект WinForms на C++/CLI? В Visual Studio давно уже нет шаблона проекта такого типа. Могу лишь в очередной раз повторить: неправильный язык выбран для написания гуевых приложений.